# Digital Ink Recognition in a browser or on server side?

Tags: google-mlkit

Is it possible to use Digital Ink Recognition on the server side or in javascript in a browser? We are trying to recognise strokes (ink) generated by digital pens and paper. Can we do the recognition using Digital Ink Recognition on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, ML Kit is focused on on-device machine learning, we support Android and iOS only.